# FireFox 3.6.3 slow after adding new plugins

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox-3.6

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 3.6.3 (Namoroka) 64bit on Windows 7 64 bit and installed lots of plugins after a new profile creation. Now its very slow. Two questions:

- How can I profile/trace out which
  plugin is slowing down my system? Do
  I need to reinstall Firefox or is it
  fine to just create another profile
  to get initial performance?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're running on an older version? It's up to 3.6.12 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an issue with the add-ons, a new profile will fix the problem. Alternatively, you should be able to disable them in the add-ons dialog, then selectively re-enable them, keeping an eye on performance as you go.

Firefox will even let you have multiple profiles and choose between them on start up.

However...

The best solution to this problem is to use the 32 bit version. Is there a reason you want to use this old 64 bit version? If you want to beta test 64 bit, get something that is actually being developed from http://nightly.mozilla.org/

Comment: i think not..because I installed the 32 bit on Windows 64 bit and Firefox crashes everytime